# Delete EKS module that has no Terraform ID

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I am getting the below error on `terraform apply`

> Error: Cannot create resource that already exists
>
> resource "kubernetes_manifest" "resource123"
>
> resource "resource123" already exists

How do I get around this if `resource123` has no Terraform ID associated with it since it is an EKS module and `kubernetes_manifest` do not have Terraform ID's associated with them, so I can't use `terraform import` without an ID.

Deleting the resource via Kubernetes still gives the same error; and I have tried deleting the `.terraform` folder and `terraform init` / `terraform apply` but that does not work as well.

Here is the Terraform for the `kubernetes_manifest`:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "secret-provider-resource123-admin-user" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1"
    "kind"       = "SecretProviderClass"
    "metadata" = {
      "namespace" = kubernetes_namespace.this.metadata[0].name
      "name"      = "resource123-admin-user"
    }
    "spec" = {
      "provider" = "aws"
      "secretObjects" = [{
        "secretName" = "resource123-admin-user"
        "type"       = "Opaque"
        data = [{
          "objectName" = "resource123-admin-user-password"
          "key"        = "password"
        }]
      }]
      "parameters" = {
        objects = yamlencode([{
          objectName  = aws_secretsmanager_secret.resource123-admin-user.name
          objectType  = "secretsmanager"
          objectAlias = "resource123-admin-user-obj"
          jmesPath = [{
            path        = "password"
            objectAlias = "resource123-admin-user-password"
          }]
        }])
      }
    }
  }
  provider = kubernetes.cluster
}
```

Comment: Please add any relevant code you have to the question.

Comment: Just added the code @MarkoE

Comment: Terraform's `import` command might help you out. For a k8s manifest it would look sort of like this `terraform import 'kubernetes_manifest.<resource_name>' '<apiVersion>/<kind>/<namespace>/<name>'` so in your case I think that would be `terraform import 'kubernetes_manifest.secret-provider-resource123-admin-user' 'secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1/SecretProviderClass/<namespace>/resource123-admin-user'`

Comment: Btw the `<namespace>` will be the actual namespace of your resource if that was not already evident.